# Text to List in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

Is there any way on how to convert a comma separated text value to a list so that I can use it with 'IN' in SQL? I used PostgreSQL for this one.

Ex.:

```
select location from tbl where 
location in (replace(replace(replace('[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]', ',[Location].[', ','''), '[Location].[', ''''), ']',''''))
```

This query:

```
select (replace(replace(replace('[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]', ',[Location].[', ','''), '[Location].[', ''''), ']',''''))
```

produces 'SG','PH'

I wanted to produce this query:

```
select location from tbl where location in ('SG','PH')
```

Nothing returned when I executed the first query. The table has been filled with location values 'SG' and 'PH'.

Can anyone help me on how to make this work without using PL/pgSQL?

Comment: Is the CSV in a column (which would be evil, nasty, and all around unpleasant) or is it coming from outside the database?

Comment: Yes it's outside the database. It's from a parameter from an MDX query. (I need to use it in Pentaho.)

Comment: What's stopping you from cleaning up the string before it goes into the database.

Comment: It doesn't work because the REPLACE function returns a TEXT type but the IN query uses a LIST. What I need is to convert the TEXT type to a LIST so that my query will work.

Comment: But why do you need to do this string processing in SQL? Why not do it before you generate the SQL? Do your tools not offer any flexibility?

Comment: It's not flexible at all. I'm doing a dashboard in Pentaho where the Location filter/parameter is used by an MDX query to display a chart and an SQL query to display a table. So the Location parameter works in MDX because it returns '[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]' but I'll have to process this string to make it work in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're faced with a *friendly* and *easy to use* tool that won't let you get any work done, I feel your pain.

A slight modification of what you have combined with [`string_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) should be able to get the job done.

First we'll replace your nested `replace` calls with slightly nicer `replace` calls:

```
=> select replace(replace(replace('[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]', '[Location].', ''), '[', ''), ']', '');
 replace 
---------
 SG,PH
```

So we strip out the `[Location].` noise and then strip out the leftover brackets to get a comma delimited list of the two-character location codes you're after. There are other ways to get the `SG,PH` using PostgreSQL's other [string and regex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) functions but `replace(replace(replace(...` will do fine for strings with your specific structure.

Then we can split that CSV into an array using `string_to_array`:

```
=> select string_to_array(replace(replace(replace('[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]', '[Location].', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), ',');
 string_to_array 
-----------------
 {SG,PH}
```

to give us an array of location codes. Now that we have an array, we can use [`= ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18025) instead of `IN` to look inside an array:

```
=> select 'SG' = any (string_to_array(replace(replace(replace('[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]', '[Location].', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), ','));
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

That `t` is a boolean TRUE BTW; if you said `'XX' = any (...)` you'd get an `f` (i.e. FALSE) instead.

Putting all that together gives you a final query structured like this:

```
select location
from tbl
where location = any (string_to_array(...))
```

You can fill in the `...` with the nested `replace` nastiness on your own.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! :) I realized that the parameter returns an array so I just added an array_to_string function to convert it to string and the query worked like a charm!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are dealing  with a comma-separated list of elements in the form `[Location].[XX]`,
I would expect this construct to perform best:

```sql
SELECT location
FROM   tbl
JOIN  (
   SELECT substring(unnest(string_to_array('[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]'::text, ',')), 13, 2) AS location
   ) t USING (location);
```

#### Step-by-step

- Transform the comma-separated list into an array and split it to a table with [`unnest(string_to_array())`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).
  You could do the same with [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). Slightly shorter but more expensive.
- Extract the `XX` part with `substring()`. Very simple and fast.
- `JOIN` to `tbl` instead of the `IN` expression. That's faster - and equivalent while there are no duplicates on either side.
  I assign the same column alias `location` to enable an equijoin with `USING`.

Answer (score 0):

Directly using location in ('something') works

I have create a fiddle that uses `IN` clause on a `VARCHAR` column

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cdf915/1

Comment: I know you can directly put the values in there. It's just that I have a different set of strings that I have to edit (using the replace query above) before using it with the 'IN' query. Those were values from an MDX query which I would like to use in an SQL query.

Comment: can you specify a sample location column data that are you manipulating on

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03860/1 but the string I need to use is a parameter from an MDX query which is '[Location].[SG],[Location].[PH]' so I'll have to remove the [Location].[] parts so that I can get 'SG' and 'PH' but like I've done in the query in my question, it doesn't work because the REPLACE function returns a TEXT type but the IN query uses a LIST. What I need is to convert the TEXT type to a LIST so that my query will work.

Comment: Please expand your answer so it stands on its own if the link breaks, or the community will likely vote to remove it.